# Stack Overflow Business is down

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, stackoverflow-business

On a lot of the SE sites (notable exception being Stack Overflow itself), there's a link to Stack Overflow Business in the footer. It links to [`https://stackoverflowbusiness.com`](https://stackoverflowbusiness.com). However, that site produces a 404 error. [The site is down.](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/stackoverflowbusiness.com).

A couple of examples of where this magic link is located:

[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/#footer):

[image: Stack Exchange]

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/#footer):

[image: Meta Stack Exchange]

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/#footer):

[image: Code Review]

Either the link is obsolete (should it perhaps point towards Stack Overflow Enterprise?), or the site has broken down.

Comment: I can confirm, though I've never heard of resty before. Popped on a status-review since I suspect this is something TPTB would really want fixed, posthaste

Comment: Fix is in the works for this, thanks for bringing to our attention

Comment: Yes,  still getting 404.

Comment: Link like https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/sitemap.xml work, so I suspect someone stripped the index.htm, or a bad redirect

Comment: @yagmoth555 nope, the link you posted does not work for me, it redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/?products.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance All stackoverflowbusiness link seem to redirect to stackoverflow blog (Check result from there, https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflowbusiness.com) , except the one that throw a 404.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.  I'm reaching to the folks that can fix this.

Update: (13:33 UTC)  Fixed.

Comment: Just curious, is this hosted somewhere else, i.e. not same host as the rest of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Could you toss a [tag:status-completed] onto the question now that it's fixed? :)

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance The redirects are handled by a different system. It redirects to a URL that is on the same cluster of hosts that run Stack Overflow. The problem was that we moved to a new redirect system and left out one item in the move.

Comment: @Spevacus Done.

Comment: Well, the link’s not broken anymore, but doesn’t it seem confusing that both “Stack Overflow” and “Stack Overflow Business” lead to the same location (for the vast majority of people, ie those without a SO account)?

Comment: Forgot one item... lol, the item that matters most. Well, glad it's all good now and thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: @Laurel That's been the case since around February, according to the Wayback Machine.